# LeanFT C# automation; Clicking on a wpf button control throwing exception

Tags: c#, testing, functional-programming, automated-tests, leanft

Getting `HP.LFT.SDK.GeneralReplayException: One or more specified arguments are not valid`, while trying to click on a wpf button (using LeanFT with C# integrated in Visual Studio 2015 )

Given the code below:

```
// Identify the "LicensingButton" button
var LicensingButton = objAdminApplicationModel.wnd_Adminstration.Describe<IButton>(new ButtonDescription
    {
        Text = @"Licensing",
        ObjectName = @"Licensing"
    });
// Click the Licensing button.
LicensingButton.Click();
```

But I am getting below exception

```
Exception is HP.LFT.SDK.GeneralReplayException: One or more specified arguments are not valid.
   at HP.LFT.SDK.Core.ClassModel.TestObjectExecuterBase.HandleReplayError(Int32 errorCode, IDictionary`2 data)
   at HP.LFT.SDK.Core.Communication.CommunicationClient.HandleError(Action`2 onError, Int32 status, IDictionary`2 data)
   at HP.LFT.SDK.Core.Communication.CommunicationClient.Send(String messageType, IDictionary`2 data, Action`2 onError)
   at HP.LFT.SDK.Core.ClassModel.TestObjectExecuter.ExecuteMethod(String methodName, Object[] arguments)
   at HP.LFT.SDK.Core.ClassModel.TestObjectBase.ExecuteMethod(String methodName, Object[] arguments)
   at HP.LFT.SDK.ClickBehaviour.Click(MouseButton button)
   at HP.LFT.SDK.UiObjectBase.<>c__DisplayClassd.<Click>b__c()
   at HP.LFT.SDK.OperationExecutionWrapper.ExecuteWithEvents(ITestObject testObject, Object additionalInfo, Action innerAction, MethodBase methodInfo, Boolean reportOnlyOnError, Object[] arguments)
   at HP.LFT.SDK.OperationExecutionWrapper.ExecuteWithEvents[T1](Action innerAction, Action`1 originalMethod, T1 param1, Boolean reportOnlyOnError, ITestObject testObject, Object additionalInfo)
   at HP.LFT.SDK.UiObjectBase.Click(MouseButton button)
   at Admin4DM.Test.Licensing.Licensing_VerifyStaticTextDisplay() in C:\Source\Automation\Test\Licensing.cs:line 32
```

Comment: Can you try calling `.Click` by explicitly specifying the  `MouseButton.Left` argument, or by providing a `ClickArgs` object with `Button` and `Location` property?

Comment: LicensingButton.Click(MouseButton.Left); is giving me the same error.

Comment: Not sure how to use the ClickArgs , can you show an example

Answer (score 1):

The exception is indeed misleading. On a first look I thought the `ButtonDescription` is incorrectly constructed, meaning that one of `Text` or `ObjectName` property expects some other value.

But that's not the case.

The problem lies entirely in the click operation. As you can see when inspecting the `Click` method, it has two overloads:

1. Expecting a `MouseButton` enum;

   When we call `Click` and we don't pass the enum or the object, `MouseButton.Left` enum value is used by default but you can also specify `.Middle` or `.Right`.
2. Expecting a `ClickArgs` object, in the form of:

   ```
   new ClickArgs {
       Button = MouseButton.Left,
       Location = Position.Center
   }
   ```

   `Location` indicates where to click the button. (`.BottomLeft`, `.BottomRight`, `.Center`, `.TopLeft` and `.TopRight`).

   Actually if we use the `MouseButton` overload, it still uses the `Position` but clicks on `Position.Center` by default.

Now that the theory is over *(phew)*, let's see what happens in practice.

The exception we see shows us that something obviously went wrong when clicking on that button, more specifically an exception was thrown while attempting to click on `Position.Center` with the `MouseButton.Left`. As `.Center` is calculated based on button's width and height property, probably there is some issue with the button that causes wrong calculations (unfortunatelly I can only assume this, I can't tell you for sure).

*<sub>By the way, if this happens on any button of the AUT you're testing, most probably the devs are doing something wrong, as it's not common (for example, on the `WPF` I'm testing, I don't have the issue on any of the buttons).</sub>*

What we can do is to attempt the followings:

1. Try clicking with `.Middle` or `.Right`;
2. Try clicking in other positions of the button using the `Position` enum;
3. Try clicking in other positions of the button using `HP.SDK.LFT.Mouse`;

   ```
   // Use Mouse class to click on the button in a fine tuned location
   var loc = LicensingButton.AbsoluteLocation;
   var p = new System.Drawing.Point(loc.X + 5, loc.Y + 5);

   Mouse.Click(p, MouseButton.Left);
   ```
4. Try identifying the object as [Insight image-based identification](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/leanft/en/latest/HelpCenter/Content/HowTo/Insight.htm);
5. Try identifying the object using [VRI](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/leanft/en/latest/HelpCenter/Content/HowTo/VRI.htm);
6. Try identifying some parent object (if possible) and execute the `Click` operation in such a way that it "hits" the button you want to actually click

Comment: Thanks Adelin. It's with all the buttons in the UI, not only with the specific one. I will try to use the ClickArgs method and will see how it goes.Currently I am working around with SendKeys method to click on any button.

Comment: I just wanted to post an update on the issue . Item 1 solution- did not work.Item 2 solution- not sure how to use the Position enum. Item 3 solution - did work; but I had to change the to loc.X+10,loc.Y+10. Did not try 4,5,6. Also I was able to duplicate the Click method issue  on the OK button found in the Login Page of the Sample WPF application (FlightGUI.exe)

Comment: Hmm I can't reproduce it on my environment on the FlightGUI application. `.Click()` works by default on the ok button